# React's reducer returns unexpected state that is not consistent with logged value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I created a reducer that increments a global UID on every dispatch with the action `increment`. The initial value of the UID is `0`.

**Expectation**:

I expected that the UID is incremented by 1 on every dispatch.

**Reality**:

The UID increments by 2 and the logged state are inconsistent with the real state's value.

My component:

```js
import React, { useReducer }  from "react"

let uid = 0

function nextUID() {
    uid = uid + 1
    return uid
}

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "increment":
            const uid = nextUID()
            const newState = `current UID is ${uid}!`
            console.log(newState)
            return newState
        default:
            return state
    }
}

function TestComponent() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, "not clicked yet")
    return <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>{state}</button>
}

export default TestComponent
```

**Output**:

| Num. Clicks | Button Label | Console Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | not yet clicked |  |
| 1 | current UID is 1! | current UID is 1! |
| 2 | current UID is 3! | current UID is 2! |
| 3 | current UID is 5! | current UID is 4! |

**Question**:

How is it possible, that the button label is `current UID is 3!` while the console output for the state change was `current UID is 2!`? Is it possible that react calls the reducer multiple times and discards the console output the second time?

**Additional Information**:

- I also tried to use `const uidRef = useRef(0)` in the `TestComponent` with an anonymous reducer that increments `uidRef.current`. The behavior was the same.
- I also tried adding a console output to `nextUID()`. The output was `new uid 1; new uid 2; new uid 4; ...`

Thanks.

Comment: Check again, you must be having some other issue, i tried this an it works as expected https://jsitor.com/DSMRz6N3Y

Comment: The issue can only be reproduced in **StrictMode**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright **StrictMode** is messing with you but in a good way. The code that you have written is undesirable as per **React**. **StrictMode** calls your `reducer` two times to eliminate any **side-effects**. In your case, the implementation of incrementing `uid` is one such **side-effect**.

**(Simply doing `console.log` wouldn't show you that reducer is being called twice since **React** silences it for second call from **17.0**. So I have used a `log` function to refer to the same `console.log`);**

Here is your code :-

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const log = console.log;

let uid = 0;

function nextUID() {
  uid = uid + 1;
  return uid;
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      log("called reducer");
      const uid = nextUID();
      const newState = `current UID is ${uid}!`;
      console.log(newState);
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function TestComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, "not clicked yet");
  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>{state}</button>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

[image: Edit React useReducer twice in strict mode]

Now your original code would work fine in production because the **reducer** would be called only once (since productions doesn't have **Strict Mode** wrapper component) but then it's not a good practice.

Following is another implementation where state is not mutated directly and so between two calls to the reducer previous state remains the same and the next increment value is consistent. If you mutated state directly like `state.val += 1`, you would see the same behaviour as your example in **Strict mode**.

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const log = console.log;

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      log("called reducer");
      const nextStateVal = state.val + 1;
      return {
        ...state,
        text: `current UID is ${nextStateVal}`,
        val: nextStateVal
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function TestComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    text: "not clicked yet",
    val: 0
  });
  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>
      {state.text}
    </button>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

[image: Edit React useReducer strict mode correct way]

Comment: Thank you very much. This explains, why the uid is incremented twice while the console logs only once.

My goal was to share a UID between multiple components. Imagine having multiple TestComponents. Clicking any TestComponent Button should then show the newest UID. I want to prevent that multple TestComponents have the same UID. Also, I need to use a reducer since i want complex state management. My above example was only a minimal code example to reproduce the issue.